# How to skip the column header in the output csv file when using CSVWRITE in h2?

Tags: csv, h2

I am migrating to h2. 
And I have a problem when exporting data to csv files. 
Due to all the csv files should be without column header.
But h2 CSVWrite function will add the column header in the csv file.

Is that possible to add one csvoption to skip outputting the column header?
It seems it doesn't have it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is currently not supported in the [CSVWRITE](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#csvwrite) function. It will be supported in the next release (support is already committed in the [H2 trunk](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/detail?r=4153), but will have to be go though the regular test and release cycle first; this will take about one or two weeks).

Comment: Thanks a lot for supporting this feature. It helps.